# Using querySelector on react markdown table when creating tests does not render immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, markdown

Hi in my React function Im replacing the already existing cell HTML in the react markdown that it have rendered with my custom one. While I was making unit tests I discovered a weird behavior that my function will render multiple times and the first time it renders the query selector array is empty. Here is what I mean

This is how I render my markdown:

```
<div className={styles.tableContainer}>
      {functionToChangeQuery()}
      {someArray.map((arr) => (
        <div key={arr.test} className={styles.markdownTable}>
          <ReactMarkdown remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}>{arr.data}</ReactMarkdown>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

This is the functionToChangeQuery:

```
  const tableHeaders = document.querySelectorAll('table > thead > tr > th');
if (tableHeaders.length > 0) {
  const firstTableHeader = tableHeaders[0];
  const alreadyExistingValue = firstTableHeader.textContent.trim();
  const newHTML = (
    <div className={styles.tableTHeadCustom}>
      <div className={styles.tableIcon}>
        <Image
          src='somesrc'
          layout="fill"
          alt="icon"
        />
      </div>
      <h1>{alreadyExistingValue}</h1>
      {!layout.isMobile && (
        <div className={styles.arrowsSection}>
          <button onClick={() => arrowOptionsChange(-1)} data-testid="arrow-left">
            <IconArrowLeft />
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => arrowOptionsChange(1)} data-testid="arrow-right">
            <IconArrowRight />
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
  ReactDOM.render(newHTML, firstTableHeader);
}
```

And this is my test (a simple one):

```
 it('render arrows', async () => {
    renderWithLayout(<MyComponent {...props} />);
    expect(screen.getByTestId('arrow-left')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

When I consoled log the tableHeaders it console logged 3 responses:

1. NodeList[]
2. NodeList(8) [th, th, th, th, th, th, th, th]
3. NodeList(8) [th, th, th, th, th, th, th, th]

It always returns the same error: `Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="arrow-right"]`

Is there a way to either make the markdown render first or in jest to make it render multiple times bcs on the first render as you can see it will give me an empty array but then it will show me the right data. Any help would be great, thanks in advance